# Why Background Image not Taking Full Width in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, react-component

**Question Details:**

I Was Trying to set the background image in react but the positioning is not working properly. The Image gets zoomed a lot, Plus when I change the property of background-size from cover to contain, It will squeeze to the center instead of taking the full width of the container.

React Component

```
import React from 'react'
import arrow from '../images/icon-arrow-down.svg'
function Showcase() {
  return (
    <div>
        <section className="showcase">
            <div className="overlay">
                <h1>We are creative</h1>
                <img src={arrow} alt="" />
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Showcase;


----------
```

CSS Code

```
**<!-- language: lang-css -->**

    /*ShowCase*/

    .showcase{
      background-image: url('./images/mobile/image-header.jpg');
      height:100vh;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center bottom;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size:  100%
    }
    .showcase .overlay{
      height:512px;
      display:flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

The Preview of Output is
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1NRu.jpg

Comment: How are you getting the classNames in? Is it an external CSS file you're importing?

Comment: What is the effect you are trying to achieve? Do you want to stretch the image?

Comment: I am to trying to create the Sunny Side Landing Page. A Challenge by Frontendmentor. I have seen people are building it using vanilla Js, but I want to create the using react Js.

Comment: I have put all my styling in global file index.css

Comment: You can check out the screenshot I have attched to better understand the problem, basically, the main section of the page has a background image. When I do the same style property in vanilla js it fixes. But when trying to do it using react app the background image got zoomed in too much

Comment: Plus one more thing I also include TailwindCss. It causing that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `background-size:  100%` from `.showcase`.

This should ensure that the size of the image can be larger than the container so your `background-position: cover` can be the full height and width of it's dimensions.

*Edit (full styles for showcase):

```
.showcase{
  background-image: url('./images/mobile/image-header.jpg');
  height:100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Have done that change, but the result is the same.

Comment: I've added the styles I used for testing which worked for me. I've also set the `width` to `100vw` and changed the `background-position` to `center`